# bind9 issue on Plesk 11

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04

I am having a problem with installing bind9 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have installed a Plesk 11 server but DNS service is not running.

```
root@cp11:~# apt-get install bind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bind is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  bind9 dnsutils dnsutils:i386 bind9:i386 manpages

E: Package 'bind' has no installation candidate
root@cp11:~# 

root@cp11:~# /etc/init.d/bind9 start
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                  [fail] 

root@cp11:~# /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                  [ OK ] 
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                  [fail]
```

When I try to check the log file:

```
root@cp11:~# tail -f /var/log/messages
tail: cannot open `/var/log/messages' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I checked in /etc and there is a bind directory

```
root@cp11:/etc/bind# ls
bind.keys  db.127  db.empty  db.root     named.conf.default-zones  named.conf.options  rndc.key
db.0       db.255  db.local  named.conf  named.conf.local          rndc.conf           zones.rfc1918
```

When I try to uninstall bind9 it also removes the Plesk control panel.

So I updated and the upgraded the packages and I see bind error:

```
root@cp11:~# apt-get upgrade
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
Processing triggers for resolvconf ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bind9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The package name is bind9 not bind. So, the installation command should be:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Make sure you have bind9 installed using the following command and then try to start it and check your logs for relevant error messages:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep bind9
```

For the system logs, there is no `/var/log/messages` file in Ubuntu 12.04. However, you can find the same information in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an issue where Apparmor was causing this in Ubuntu.
So try #/etc/init.d/apparmor teardown then try again